# Add file extension before downlaoding the file from Objectstore in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

My .jsx file is like:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Download = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const { run } = this.props;

        let url = `./objectstore?uri=${run.path}`;

        return (
            <div className="runData">
                <p><strong>Download Link:</strong><a href={url} target="_blank">{run.path}</a></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Download;
```

Here I am getting object store path in {run.path} where file is stored as "abc".
Now I want to download that file as "abc.csv" (adding the extension or in form of csv/xml).

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try just adding `.csv` after your `run.path`? If the actual file is encoded in CSV I guess just adding the extension should be fine?

Comment: run.path has the object store path. If I add .csv to it, the path will be changed and became an invalid path. I want to add .csv extension to the file which is going to download when we click on the URL.

Comment: This can be set by the hosting server, using the [Content-Dispositon header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).

For example: `Content-Disposition: inline; filename = "report_data.csv"`.

You can also do this on the client but it's more complex, as you'll have to first make javascript download the file in memory and then have the browser download the file to disk (see https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/).